# Java - Oracle data use

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, netbeans

Does anyone know how to use data from Oracle database in Java Netbeans?
I have successfully connected the database to Netbeans but I do not know how to actually use this data. All I have done is to create Entity classes from database and JPA Controller classes from Entity Classes which contains methods for CRUD functionality but I do not know how to use them.
Here is an example of a "Insert" button:

```
    Staff s1 = new Staff();
    s1.setStaffId(txtId.getText());


    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PCR4B"); 
    StaffJpaController ajc = new StaffJpaController(emf);
    try {
        ajc.create(s1);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StaffGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with this part of code? For some reason I get many errors but I am not sure if they come from this part of code or not.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I get many errors" And what might these errors be?

Answer (score 0):

It's too many errors to display them here. The build is successful though.
I was wondering if there is a way to store the data of a table in an ArrayList and then use the ArrayList to make changes to elements and then store them back to the database?

The JPA controller class provides the CRUD functionality but I do not know how to make use of the functions. I do not understand what the EntityManager is.